# Creating first letters of names based on if there are already first letters and add a dot

Tags: excel, vba

I hope someone can help me with this complicated question tho!

This code checks the names in column E, then creates for each name in column E a first letter in column D and adds an dot.

For example if there is a name called Dave in column E it creates `D.` in column D.

For exmaple if there is a name called Dave Rick in column E it create `D.E.` in column D.

So what I would like to change in this code is that if there is already a firstletter or second or third in column D then it should not do anything besides putting a dot. If there isn't one and if there is not a firstletter in column E, it should automatically put the first letters of the names in column E in column D with a dot.

```
Dim cell As Range

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E" & lastRow)
    S = ""
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        V = Split(cell.Value, " ")
        For Each W In V
            S = S & Left$(W, 1) & "."
        Next W
        cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value = S
    End If
Next cell
```

Screenshot:

[image: Example:]

Extra screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Not sure i understand. Could you elaborate, show an example?  Is the E from column E?

Comment: Why does `Dave` get `D.` and `Dave Rick` gets `D.E.` I don't get this pattern. Please clarify and/or give more examples. Checkout [mcve] and give a full example of input and output data for all types of data you have.

Comment: Yes so if people have more then 1 name it should get all the firstletters of the names an create more initials so thats why it becomes D.E.

I have added a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for your example. What about John von Neumann? J.v.N.? J.V.N? or something else?

Comment: @NicholasHunter `John von Neumann` is probably not a first name. So he would only be `John` and surname `von Neumann`.

Comment: Ah yes good question the insertion of the names is handeld automatically when I import these names from a csv file.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yes thats exact!

Comment: @UlquiorraSchiffer I still don't get what is wrong with your code. It looks like it does what you show in the screenshot. Can you provide an example where your code does not do what you want?

Comment: Yes it does, but if there are already some first letters in lets say in the example column B, the code just replaces them. It should only add a dot if there isn't one in front of the firstletter or firstletters, because sometimes we get this info with multiple firstletters and only one firstname. 

So it should not overwrite column B if there are already multiple/single firstletters.
It should check if every firstletter has a dot in front.
And if there isn't any firstletter it creates it like the code already does.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I have added a another screenshot hopefully its a bit better understanable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `cell` contains a value just replace spaces with dots and append one dot in the end.

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E" & lastRow)
    S = ""
    If ActiveSheet.Range("B" & cell.Row) <> "" Then 'Adjust "B" to be the column with the initials
        'If initals exist re-format them with dots.
        Dim FixValue As String
        FixValue = cell.Value
        FixValue = Replace$(FixValue , ". ", ".") 'this will turn `D. Z. K.` into `D.Z.K.` as the other patterns
        FixValue = Replace$(FixValue , " ", ".") & "." 'this will turn `D Z K` into `D.Z.K.`
        cell.Value = FixValue 
    ElseIf cell.Value <> "" Then
        'If no initals exist but a first name exists then turn name into initials
        V = Split(cell.Value, " ")
        For Each W In V
            S = S & Left$(W, 1) & "."
        Next W
        cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value = S
    End If
Next cell
```

That's it.

Comment: Check I gonna try this in 30 min!

Comment: Would this turn result, say `D..J..K..` if `D. J. K.` was present in the cell?

Comment: I'm starting to feel a regular expression coming on...

Comment: @NicholasHunter I was actually right now thinking about it. Because it is very unclear why `D. Z. K.` has to be nothing. According the pattern I think it should remove the spaces there and be `D.Z.K.`

Comment: Quick fix could be simply using `Split()` to check for presence of `.` and if `Ubound > 0 Then Replace...`

Comment: The longer I look at the 2nd screenshot the harder it becomes.

Comment: Applied another fix as I think `D. Z. K.` should actually be `D.Z.K.` (without spaces) otherwise the pattern doesn't make any sense. If that is not what the OP is looking for I suggest regular expressions.

Comment: Shouldn't _If cell.Value <> "" Then_ be _If cell.Value = "" Then_? A small point, but enough to have some people come back and complain "I tried your code but it does not work!" Not this OP obviously, but some people.

Comment: @NicholasHunter You are right he is not looping through the initials but through the first names column. I got confused because the column names in the screenshot did not match the code. I adjusted the code so this should work now.